# Uninstall Vshieldscanner OSX

Tags: terminal, catalina, search, macos

When I first got my Mac about 4 years ago, I thought it'd be sensible to install McAfee VShield that was offered by my network provider. Soon learned this was unnecessary and not recommended.

I can't remember how I uninstalled it as it was four years ago. However I today deleted around 5 files from LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents that contained reference to McAfee. I became aware of them as my Filr app highlighted that Vshieldscanner was being blocked by my administrator. Didn't know what it was, but found out it that was part of McAfee.

Is there a way of locating where the Vshieldscanner files are located so that I can manually remove them; all visible McAfee files were deleted long ago, and the Daemon files are now all gone too.

I've searched the internet and found others have had issues with uninstalling McAfee. All I can see on my machine is the Vsheildscanner. From [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1492375/how-do-i-uninstall-mcafee-antivirus-from-mac) I found these steps, but following them I still have the Vsheildscanner error message with my filr app.

Comment: There’s usually an uninstaller that accompanies the McAfee software.  Look in the Applications or Utilities folders for this tool.  You can also try [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

Comment: Hi @Allan, this uninstaller does not exist on my computer, that was the first thing that I looked for. All files and apps associated with McAfee are long gone, all residual components are hidden away somewhere. I've been reluctant to use an app cleaner, as I'd feel safer to remove them manually.

Comment: Then check with McAfee - sometimes an uninstaller is a separate download, sometimes it's packed inside the original installer.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've done that

Comment: You can reinstall the app so you grt the uninstaller; then run it to properly remove everything.  What about App Cleaner I mentioned?  Did you try the McAfee support forums?

Comment: @Allan, the version I had was offered by my network provider and I am no longer eligible for it. The app cleaner will not be suitable as I removed the McAfee app years ago, but remnants remain and are causing the issues. So what I need to be able to do is locate those remaining components and remove them manually.

Comment: That's what App Cleaner does.

Comment: @ Allan, yes but if I don't have the app, how can I tell the App cleaner to remove the hidden files? I would much rather do it manually than install another app or program onto my computer, it would be more valuable to me to be able to do it myself instead of relying on third part software.